# Jenkins Failed to connect to gitlab port 443

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I try to connect to the gitlab from Jenkins and I keep getting this error:

```
Started by user Marko Zadravec
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/...
using credential ...
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.xxxx.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.xxxx.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials new correct
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://gitlab.xxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://gitlab.xxxx.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:894)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1161)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://gitlab.xxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxxx.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.xx.si port 443: Connection timed out

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:892)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

But, if run the command in terminal on the same machine on witch Jenkins is installed,...

```
git fetch --tags --progress https://gitlab.xxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

it is working,...

### EDIT:

For git I use User and a password

[image]

### EDIT 2

I now found out, that fetching git stop working on all my previous projects,... 
I suspect that this mean that user is not a problem, but something else,...

Do anyone have some idea where to look for problem?

Comment: It looks as if your Jenkins environment is not using SSH key/token and `git` commands are therefore unauthorized. Can you check, if your Jenkins environment contains some way of authorization and if it is used properly? Another possible explanation would be, that your Jenkins environment is using an gitlab user account (or its SSH/token key) which is not added to the project from which you are trying to fetch.

Comment: I am using the User, witch is admin on git project... I add the picture

Comment: @Václav, are you sure (and why/how) that this error is due to authentication?